How to refactor a couple of fields from one model to another with FK relation
I currently have a model
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    manufacturer_url = models.URLField()

Now I would like to extract the manufacturer information into its own model, so that I can get rid of redundant data. Like so:
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    url = models.URLField()

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Doing this however the Django migration tool just detects this as "delete fields" and "add fields". Can Django somehow do this migration automatically? Or will I have to write those migrations myself. It seems like a common use case, so I figured maybe Django has something in store for ootb.

Use two steps for migration: first add the model with the URL, then perform a data migration, and finally remove the manufacturer_url.

No as far as my knowledge there is nothing in django to deal with this situation
What i suggest is first dont delete the manufacturer_name field from cars:
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    url = models.URLField()

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    manufacturer_url = models.URLField()
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

##then using 
python manage.py shell 
from app.models import *
getallcars = Car.objects.all()
for car in getallcars:
    getmanufacturer,created = Manufacturer.objects.getorcreate(name=car.manufacturer_name ,manufacturer_url =car.manufacturer_url)

Then you can delete manufacturer_name and manufacturer_url
